# How to set group by column-name as column instead of index?(Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

I have a dataframe:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby("DATE").sum()
```

The dataframe looks like:

[image]

The group by column `DATE` is shown as index here. I want the column `DATE` to be a separate column rather than index.

The condition is that `grouped_df['DATE']` should display the data instead of an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
grouped_df = df.groupby("DATE", as_index=False).sum()
# or
grouped_df = df.groupby("DATE").sum().reset_index()
```